# Convert Byte Array to image in Java - without knowing the type

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Sounds simple right? Use

```
ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Here's the wrinkle. For some reason it is detecting a jpeg as a bmp, and that is the first ImageReader returned when I call

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
Iterator<ImageReader> readers=ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
```

This causes the image to come out corrupted. Is there a way to tell through java short of looking directly at the bytes for the header, and failing that does anyone know of a good reference for the byte headers for the different images?

Just letting you guys know I am still working on this. I'll let you know if/when I have an answer. I thank all of you for your responses so far.

Comment: [This page](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html) might be a good starting point for magic numbers. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) is something similar from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't played with ImageIO in a awhile, and have not tested this, but I seem to recall something like this working.  (since you say you know your file is a jpg and not a bitmap, I am using that information to help find the right loader).

```
String inFormat = "jpg";

Iterator inReaders = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName(inFormat);

...

nextInReader.setInput( iis );
```

Comment: That's correct but the problem is the data collection is a mix of bmp, png, jpg, etc. So any of them COULD be valid, the trick is telling which one solely based upon the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference you can have a look at wikipedia, you can find the header of the different formats there.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Answer (score -1):

Is the BMP reader the *only* one returned by `getImageReaders()`? Maybe you get more than one and can make a choice based on that.