# Convert byte array (byte[]) to Image in Java

Tags: java, image, byte, jpeg2000

I have a `byte[]` that I want to convert to an Image and display the image in a label.
The byte[] is of a jpeg 2000 format.
I have tried the code below but it returns null:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
```

The image value comes back as `null`.

I want to be able to display the image in a label like below:

```
jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662916/read-jpeg2000-files-in-java

Comment: My guess is that your input data is incorrect. Please show how you've obtained the data.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212882/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-java-without-knowing-the-type

Answer (score 13):

To convert an array of bytes, i.e. `byte[]` into an `Image`, use `getImage()`. Probably the easiest way to do this is to instantiate an `ImageIcon` using the `ImageIcon(byte[])` constructor, and then call `getImage()`. This is illustrated in the method below, particularly the last line:

```
public Image createImage(){
   //ccurve.png
   byte[] b = {-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82,
      0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 15, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 59, -42, -107,
      74, 0, 0, 0, 64, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, -38, 99, 96, -64, 14, -2,
      99, -63, 68, 1, 100, -59, -1, -79, -120, 17, -44, -8, 31, -121, 28, 81,
      26, -1, -29, 113, 13, 78, -51, 100, -125, -1, -108, 24, 64, 86, -24, -30,
      11, 101, -6, -37, 76, -106, -97, 25, 104, 17, 96, -76, 77, 97, 20, -89,
      109, -110, 114, 21, 0, -82, -127, 56, -56, 56, 76, -17, -42, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 73, 69, 78, 68, -82, 66, 96, -126};
   return new ImageIcon(b).getImage();
}
```

I think this can by used for `png`, `gif`, `bmp`, and `jpg` images. Also the byte array does not have to be hard-coded, as in this example.

If you want an `ImageIcon` instead of an `Image`, don't call `getImage()`:

```
public ImageIcon createImageIcon(){
   //ccurve.png
   byte[] b = {-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82,
      0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 15, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 59, -42, -107,
      74, 0, 0, 0, 64, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, -38, 99, 96, -64, 14, -2,
      99, -63, 68, 1, 100, -59, -1, -79, -120, 17, -44, -8, 31, -121, 28, 81,
      26, -1, -29, 113, 13, 78, -51, 100, -125, -1, -108, 24, 64, 86, -24, -30,
      11, 101, -6, -37, 76, -106, -97, 25, 104, 17, 96, -76, 77, 97, 20, -89,
      109, -110, 114, 21, 0, -82, -127, 56, -56, 56, 76, -17, -42, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 73, 69, 78, 68, -82, 66, 96, -126};
   return new ImageIcon(b);
}
```

Then you can call `jlabel.setIcon(createIconImage());`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(user.getBytes());
```

The above is how its worked for me in the past where user has a profile picture simply stored in a byte array. The servlet realizes this and outputs the image.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I get the byte[] from a web service. I send the User ID and fingerprint to the web service where the image is stored, so If they are correct I get the byte[] back.

Comment: Sure, but it is generally the browser rather than Java that turns the `byte[]` back to an image, so I can't see your answer as being relevant.

Comment: @user  Please move your comment from this answer to the question.  That way Jon will be informed of it (AFAIU).