# How do I display images on the browser submitted to the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

The following servlet code,gets the image bytes from the database's table.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessFact = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sessFact.openSession();
    pojo.File image_file = (pojo.File)sess.get(pojo.File.class, 2);
    byte image_file_bytes[] = image_file.getFiles_uploaded(); 

    // NOW WHAT ? HOW DO I MAKE IT DISPLAY IN THE BROWSER ?
}
```

I have the `bytes`. What do I do next to display image on to the browser ?

Comment: Check what happens when you set the `response` header and write the bytes to the `ServletoutputStream` !

Comment: try this 

[Convert byte array (byte[]) to Image in Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119472/convert-byte-array-byte-to-image-in-java

Comment: try this 

[Convert byte array (byte[]) to Image in Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119472/convert-byte-array-byte-to-image-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the OutputStream of the HttpServletResponse to write the data out.