# How to show large byte array in JLabel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, bitmap, resize

I have two Swing GUI.I successfully transferred some information between each other.

My problem is that,i try to show byte array in JLabel. I wrote code, but I can't show my image, because byte array is large. Here is source

```
jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(byteArray);
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
jPanel1.add(label);
```

I tested another small byte array (I inserted it in google) and it's working.
Is it a possible to resize byte array before put in in another GUI?
How i can solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question has a working answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119472/convert-byte-array-byte-to-image-in-java).

Basically, you have to convert your byte[] array to an ImageIcon object first and then add it to your label.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks your atthention. I also found this question and tested it.As you can see there is a static byte array,when i tested it ,it's worked,but not working when i use my byte array @xoX Zeus Xox

Comment: Could you please provide more of your code that is relevant to this question, e.g. your byte array declaration and initialization?

Comment: @Baggio, `when i tested it ,it's worked,` - so you have proven the concept of using a byte array works. `but not working when i use my byte array` - then your byte array doesn't contain valid data.