# Create Image using a byte[] bytes for pixels

Tags: java, image, io

I've been working with storing data in pictures as a fun side project. I have managed to create an image using bytes loaded from another image. However, I would like to take any array of bytes and save the array of bytes as pixels in an image using java. What would be the best approach and how should I calculate the height width ect. Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand the format of your input. Maybe you can try  ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)).

Comment: You might need this for references: > [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file) and this > [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212882/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-java-without-knowing-the-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212882/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-java-without-knowing-the-type)