# Extract image's width, height, color and type from byte array

Tags: java, image

I have an image in the format of `byte[]` array in my Java code. I want the following information extracted from that array. How can I do it as fast as possible.

- Width
- Height
- Color (black & white, color or transparent? If color, what is the main color?)
- Type (Is the image PNG, GIF, JPEG, etc.)

Comment: Extracting that kind of information using just bitwise operations on your byte array is a big task. I'd use some library for that.

Comment: Create image of some kind (maybe using `ImageIO`) and extract the image properties

Comment: @Simon I don't have any problem using a library.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use ImageIO to read as buffered image and then get relevant things which you want. See java doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // assuming that picture is your byte array
        byte[] picture = new byte[30];

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(picture);

        BufferedImage buf = ImageIO.read(in);
        ColorModel model = buf.getColorModel();
        int height = buf.getHeight();

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please give me a code snippet? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Especially for the color part.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How about the color information? Is it possible with the `BufferedImage`? Thanks.

Comment: See the edit. ColorModel has all the color related information. Api doc is  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html

Comment: Thanks. And if possible, please let me know how I should get the `type` for instance png, jpeg, etc.

Comment: Have a look at API for this.I Never did that

Answer (score 7):

To get the **image type from the byte array**, you can do something like:

```
byte[] picture = new byte[30];
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(picture));

Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
while (readers.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader read = readers.next();
    System.out.println("format name = " + read.getFormatName());
}
```

Here is the output I have for different files:

```
format name = png
format name = JPEG
format name = gif
```

It was inspired from:

[Convert Byte Array to image in Java - without knowing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212882/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-java-without-knowing-the-type)